# Tracking someone who is deleting mails in a shared Gmail

Tags: gmail

We have a group of 25 people who have a common Gmail. Unfortunately, someone is deleting all the new mails. Can someone tell me if we could trace from where the mail are being deleted, please?

Comment: From regular Gmail, no. Google Apps Email may have some different logging capabilities. This shows why sharing a mailbox is a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: If everyone use different systems, you can get some idea from last login details.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible.

Gmail mailboxes don't have a user detailed activity log. Only the access to the mailbox are recorded in the Last account activity. This could help just in case that the messages were deleted very recently and the users have devices with different IP addresses.

It's worth saying that sharing the account and password of an Google account and signing-in from several devices in certain circumstances could block it. Instead, use Gmail delegation or use a group of Google Groups as a collaborative mailbox. Unfortunately this will not help you to track message deletions either, so you should consider to use another kind of app, like a CRM web app.

**References**
[Last account activity - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en)
[Set up mail delegation - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en)
[Use a group as a collaborative inbox - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, sharing an email account is fraught with difficulties, and generally isn't a good idea. There are alternatives, though. For incoming mail, you could convert the address to a broadcast mailing list, such that all emails to common_email@example.com would be sent to everyone who currently accesses the account common_email@example.com. You could even have a central archive where authorized users could view all incoming mail.

For outgoing mail, you could set each potential sender up with the ability to appear as if they're sending from common_email@example.com. It might take some creative email client configuration, but it can be done (albeit with some limitations).

Answer (score 1):

It may be innocent.  If someone has set a program to download new emails it may be downloading them with the POP protocol

Try changing the password and then asking everyone to check-in or turn off support for POP protocol

**POP Download:**

1. Status: POP is enabled for all mail
2. When messages are accessed with **POP DELETE EMAIL IN GMAIL**