# With a common Gmail ID for a group of users will people signing in from different locations at the same time be blocked?

Tags: gmail, sharing

If I create a common Gmail ID for a group of users (about 100) for a specific purpose (like sharing PDFs) will it block people from signing in, if they are logging in from different locations and different PCs and apps, at the same time?

<sub>When I don't want to create a Google group.</sub>

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79109/88163

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Probably yes.

## Explanation

Google accounts have security and abuse prevention controls that could block when they detect suspicious activity.

As Google accounts are intended to be used by single users sharing one of them to a hundreds of users could make the account to be blocked. This could be for a short time or permanently.